# Too many files to rename

Tags: powershell

Renaming pdf-files with the command

```
get-childitem | % { rename-item $_ "2017-$_"}
```

renames correctly 33 files but applying the same command to more than 33 files produces filenames looking like 2017-2017-2017...-original.name.

How can I surmount that limitation for which I have not found any explication?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally re-rename already renamed files yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Since Rename-Item accepts piped input there is no need for a ForEach,
to exclude files beginning with `2017-` :

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf -exclude 2017-*.pdf | 
    Rename-Item -Newname { $_.Name -replace '^','2017-' } -whatif
```

to exclude any year/4digit-number prefix :

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
  Where-Object Name -notmatch '^\d{4}-' |
    Rename-Item -Newname { $_.Name -replace '^','2017-' } -whatif
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-whatif`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is chasing it's tail (i.e. it's renaming things that have already been renamed). Capture the list of files into a variable, then loop through that, renaming the captured list of files:

```
$filesToRename = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.pdf'
$filesToRename | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "2017-$($_.FullName)"
}
```

If you want to exclude already renamed files:

```
$prefix = '2017-'
$filesToRename = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.pdf' | Where-Object { !$_.Name.StartsWith($prefix) }
$filesToRename | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$prefix$($_.FullName)"
}
```